# Быстрое вступление в силу изменений классах

Tags: java, веб-программирование, оптимизация, веб-сервер

В веб приложениях на Java часто приходится менять код в .java файлах.
Чтобы изменения вступили в силу, мне приходится (в Intellij IDEA) либо делать рестарт сервера, либо редеплой. И то и то занимает иногда много времени, если учитывать то, что изменений приходится делать много и часто. 
Если я выбираю опцию (при запуске приложения из idea) update classes and resources, то изменения не вступают в силу.

Подскажите, как можно ускорить этот процесс?

Comment: Попробуй [spring loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded)

Comment: Спасибо! Но уже нашел более простой способо для idea:
1) артифак должен быть exploded
2) запускать приложени надо в режиме Debug
3) А затем либо кликть по дебагу и выббирать update classes and resources или для On frame deactivation выбрать update classes and resources
4) output билда класть в папку target